# Problems installing NGINX 1.24 on AIX 7.1

Tags: nginx, compiler-errors, aix

I am trying to download NGINX 1.24 on AIX 7.1. I configured pcre-master and then configured NGINX with the same pcre-master. It seemed going well, but upon trying to "make" command, I get the following errors :

```
"src/os/unix/ngx_gcc_atomic_ppc.h", line 94.1: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"src/os/unix/ngx_gcc_atomic_ppc.h", line 91.8: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for inline.
"src/os/unix/ngx_gcc_atomic_ppc.h", line 138.12: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier value.
"src/core/ngx_rbtree.h", line 78.1: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"src/core/ngx_rbtree.h", line 76.8: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for inline.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 19.3: 1506-273 (E) Missing type in declaration of ngx_str_t.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 23.5: 1506-046 (S) Syntax error.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 69.1: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 67.8: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for inline.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 220.3: 1506-273 (E) Missing type in declaration of ngx_str_node_t.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 225.1: 1506-166 (S) Definition of function ngx_str_node_t requires parentheses.
"src/core/ngx_string.h", line 225.16: 1506-276 (S) Syntax error: possible missing '{'?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 25.34: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text fd encountered.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 25.5: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier ngx_fd_t.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 27.3: 1506-273 (E) Missing type in declaration of ngx_file_mapping_t.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 117.1: 1506-166 (S) Definition of function ngx_fd_t requires parentheses.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 117.10: 1506-276 (S) Syntax error: possible missing '{'?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 147.18: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier fd.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 147.22: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier buf.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 147.27: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier n.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 169.43: 1506-046 (S) Syntax error.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 196.54: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ')' or ','?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 196.11: 1506-282 (S) The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 197.48: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ')' or ','?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 197.6: 1506-282 (S) The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 219.34: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ')' or ','?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 219.11: 1506-282 (S) The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 251.1: 1506-277 (S) Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
"src/os/unix/ngx_files.h", line 249.8: 1506-485 (S) Parameter declaration list is incompatible with declarator for inline.
"src/os/unix/ngx_shmem.h", line 19.18: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text name encountered.
"src/os/unix/ngx_shmem.h", line 22.3: 1506-273 (E) Missing type in declaration of ngx_shm_t.
make: The error code from the last command is 1.
```

I tried many versions of pcre , and only could work around getting a pcre-master with ./configure setup. I am using /usr/vac/bin/xlc as the C compiler.

Comment: Using `gcc` might give you better results, especially combined with `gas`
Or you could try and use binary package from here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha#N